# How to join 2 tables using SQL

Tags: sql-server

I created two temporary tables, #tableA (1872 entries) and #tableB (1146 entries). I have populated both with mailing info. I want to filter out the entries from #tableA that also show up in #tableB (437 shared entries). I want to do this by looking at the FullName field found in both temp tables. After we filter these shared names out I need to return the data from #tableA (which now has 1435 entries).

```
select * from #TableA
--inner join #TableB ON #TableA.FullName = #TableB.FullName --shows 437 shared names
where 
--#TableA.FullName <> #TableB.FullName --this is obviusly not going to work
```

Could you guys please point me in the right direction?

thank you

Comment: `Except`?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Comment: If you use proper joins it is highly likely you don't even need the temp tables but it is hard to know for sure without knowing more about your actual process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select a.*
from #TableA a
left join #TableB b ON a.FullName = b.FullName
where b.FullName IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

I rather advise you to learn joins. If you don't know it- you need to! Otherwise you will be asking others to do it for you.

[image]

Comment: I printed it out and put it on my desk. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?  It creates a CTE containing only entries where they match, then filters those out in the select statement.

```
;with aggTable as(
select ta.FullName
from #tableA ta
inner join #tableB tb
on ta.FullName = tb.FullName
)
select *
from #tableA ta
where ta.FullName not in aggTable
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you all the records from TableA and any matching records from TableB. Records that are not present in TableB will be NULL.

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.*
FROM
  #TableA a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #TableB b
    ON a.FullName = b.FullName
```